# Unable to debug the WPF application (xaml.cs) in VS 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xaml

I have been working on some WPF windows and user controls which are part of the class library project running in VS 2010. I set some debug points in the XAML.cs file and they were hit properly.

However, suddenly I am not able to debug the xaml.cs. All other breakpoints which are not set on the XAML.cs are hit without any problem.

I cleaned the solution, closed and reopened it, rebooted the machine but no success!

Any idea how can i troubleshoot further?

I am running Windows 7 machine.

Comment: May be execution not coming to the line where you have put the breakpoint?

Comment: @CharithJ: This is not the case. I have set breakpoint on button click and I am clicking the button. Another breakpoint is in constructor of the window. Window shows up but breakpoint is not hit !

Comment: Can you show the code and the place where you put the breakpoint?

Comment: This problem is solved. I found that somehow the assembly lying in the bin folder of the main application was old. When I added 'project reference' of the assembly, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line where you want to debug and see whether the execution comes to the line where you have put the breakpoint.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

**EDIT**

> it stops on other breakpoints but not on the ones set in xaml.cs files.

May be the execution not coming to the line where you have put the breakpoint.

Comment: Are you saying it stops on other breakpoints but not in this one?

Comment: Yes, it stops on other breakpoints but not on the ones set in xaml.cs files. Surprisingly they were working until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. I found that somehow the assembly lying in the bin folder of the main application was old. When I added 'project reference' of the assembly, the problem is solved!

Comment: That means you haven't cleaned the solution. Contradicts your question.

Comment: No, the solution was cleaned but the copy command on the project build event was wrong. I added project reference and removed the copy command.